# Set up emails with ** SPAM in the title to go the the user's junk E-mail folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I have a spam filter that will mark all emails it thinks are spam as  ** SPAM Email Title Here **

I'd like to still send these to the users but make a rule that if ** SPAM is in the title to send it to the Junk mail folder.

Is there a way I can do this globally for all 2000+ users in Exchange 2010? Google has failed me(or I failed Google :P).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this.
Under Organizational Configuration -> Transport Rules
You can create a new rule that
If ** SPAM is in the Title, set the spam confidence level to 9.
This puts all of these in the proper Junk folder.

I did end up writing

```
Get-Mailbox | foreach { 
Remove-Inboxrule -Mailbox datacore -Identity “SpamBlocking”
New-InboxRule SpamBlocking -Mailbox $_.Name -SubjectContainsWords '*** SPAM' -MoveToFolder '$_:\Junk E-Mail' -MarkImportance 'Low'
}
```

That should also work but I never ended up testing it.

Answer (score 1):

From quick look this should be possible with some powershell scripting : http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/managing-inbox-rules-exchange-server-2010.html

In a nutshell, you would need to pull the users list and then iterate through it using Set-InboxRule cmdlet

Comment: Pretty cool procedure, I found a much simpler way, however :)